# Python's assert isinstance not working for type hinting in Visual Studio, but only for datetime.date

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, type-hinting, isinstance

The code below has the tool tip "`myDate: <unknown type>`" when I mouse over `myDate`.

```
from datetime import date
assert isinstance(myDate,date)
```

This only seems to happen with types from `datetime`. I have no problem with built-ins, like `dict`, other libraries like `pypyodbc.Connection` or my own user-defined classes because with these types Visual Studio shows the type hint as expected.

Why does this happen and why only with datetime classes?

[image: Visual Studio showing the issue]

Comment: This seems like a bug with Visual Studios -- maybe try filing an issue on their bug tracker?

Comment: Were you able to recreate it?

Comment: @Michael0x2a I'm checking their bug tracker: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/119042/pythons-assert-isinstance-not-working-for-type-hin.html

Comment: Is this allowed? given that you've not defined `myDate`?

Comment: @will this behaviour is observed even if inside a function. Eg def func(myDate):